# DXA Java 2.0: How do I access a field value in a component linked in DXA page metadata?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, java

In order to avoid translating pages we've added a linked component in our page metadata.

[image]

I've created a custom page model:

```
@Data
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "MyPageModel", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, public_ = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class MyPageModel extends DefaultPageModel {

    @JsonProperty("MyLinkedPageMetaData")
    @SemanticProperty("myLinkedPageMetaData")
    public MyLinkedPageMetaData myLinkedPageMetaData;

}
```

I've registered this in my initializer:

```
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "MyPageTemplate", modelClass = MyPageModel.class)
```

I've create the model for the linked component schema:

```
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "MyLinkedPageMetaData", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, public_ = true)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class MyLinkedPageMetaData extends AbstractEntityModel{  
    @JsonProperty("PageTitle")
    @SemanticProperty("pageTitle")
    public String pageTitle;
}
```

I'm trying to access this in my view via:

```
<jsp:useBean id="pageModel" type="com.client.dxawebapp.model.page.MyPageModel" scope="request" />

${pageModel.myLinkedPageMetaData.pageTitle}
```

However the value is never written out, it's just blank.

When I write out ${pageModel.meta} I see "myLinkedPageMetaData=''".

Previewing the page I see:

```
"Metadata": {
  "nonTranslatedTitle": "Test title",
  "myLinkedPageMetaData": {
    "$type": "EntityModelData",
    "Id": "20953",
    "ComponentTemplate": {
      "Id": "10581",
      "RevisionDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    "Folder": {
      "Id": "1058",
      "Title": "Page Metadata Components"
    },
    "Content": {
      "pageTitle": "Page title in linked component",
    },
    "SchemaId": "20952"
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I obtain the values in my linked component in DXA 2.0 Java?

Note: The same approach works fine in DXA 2.0 .Net.

To add with it the template output of the page contains tcm id for that component link field but it got empty in front end DXA java app. tried with text field to have tcm id it behaves same.

[image]

[image]

And there is sperate metadata in json which we couldn't use it in page model from template output its having template as "Generate Data Presentation" not sure where its configured to use that.[image]

Comment: What is the root element name of your linked Component? The semantic entity name of `MyLinkedPageMetadata` should match the root element name.

Comment: Furthermore, the `MyLinkedPageMetadata` View Model should also be registered.

Comment: Thanks Rick. The root element name is indeed "myLinkedPageMetaData" (same as the semantic entity name). Do you have an example of how the MyLinkedPageMetadata model should be registered please? I tried this 

`@RegisteredViewModel(modelClass = MyLinkedPageMetadata.class)`

Comment: The semantic entity name is “MyLinkedPageMetaData” (initial capital) is that exactly the same as the root element name? Note that if the semantic entity name is exactly the same as the class name, the `@SemanticEntity` annotation is redundant.

Comment: Your way to register the View Model looks fine to me.

Comment: I updated everything to uppercase but still no luck. I'm wondering if the Java version of DXA isn't set up to expand the viewmodel properties when it's page metadata

Comment: AFAIK, this should work for Java too. You could try to use the same (embedded) View Model in the Entity Model for a Component Presentation to see if it does work in that context.

Comment: How many levels your link depth resolver configured?

Comment: 5 levels - we see the values written into the metadata when we preview the page